# Attenuation and Insertion Loss for a 2 port network

Tags: rf, power-electronics, electromagnetism, transmission-line, microwave

in my university lectures the insertion loss and the attenuation of a 2 port network have been defined in the following way (and I have an extremely basic question about them):

- the **Lnsertion Loss L** is the ratio between the power transferred from a voltage generator to a load when directly connected (figure 1) and the power transferred from a source to a load when connected through a two port network (figure 2):

[image]

By solving some equations with S parameters, this is the final expression of L:

[image]

As you can easily see, it depends not only on the network S parameters, but also on the load and source properties.

- Attenuation is defined as the Insertion Loss evaluated when the reflection coefficients of the source and of the load are zero:

[image]

**My question is**: which is the meaning of defining the attenuation when \$\Gamma_{g} = 0\$? This condition means that \$b_{g} = 0\$, so no power is trasmitted to the two port network (and so to the load).

My book says that \$\Gamma_{g}\$ takes into account of the reflection of the power coming from the network (which is generated through the reflection of the source power at port 1 and port 2). I may understand this, but I think that globally \$b_{g}\$ is the direct traveling wave from the source to the network, and so if it is 0, no power is transmitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: you have your notation backwards from what I believe to be convention. \$b\$ refers to the outgoing wave from the network and \$a\$ refers to the wave incident on the network. That being said, the following will use your notation instead.

---

When \$\Gamma_g=0\$, what is implied is that the source impedance of your generator at port 1 is matched to the port's impedance. This means that any wave coming out of port 1 will be completely absorbed by the source's impedance and no wave will be reflected back into the network. However, the source is generating it's own wave which is incident on the network. Thus, the total wave incident on port 1 of the network would be 
$$ b_g=\Gamma_g a_g + V_g = 0 + V_g = V_g$$
where \$V_g\$ is the voltage wave generated by the source. \$b_g\$ is not zero, like you mentioned. It is this voltage wave that is transmitted, and against which you calculated the attenuation.

You have to remember that the S parameters of a network and defined independent from what's connected to the network. The only thing you need to know is each port's reference impedances (which are usually all taken to be \$50\Omega\$ in standard microwave systems). Attaching a source to port 1 requires that you include the source's voltage in \$b_g\$. The equation involving \$a_L\$ would now read (assuming matched ports)
$$ a_L = S_{21} b_g + S_{22} b_L = S_{21} V_g + S_{22}*0 = S_{21} V_g $$
Then the attenuation according to your definition is 
$$ \frac{|V_g|^2}{|a_L|^2} = \frac{1}{|S_{21}|^2} $$

Note again that this answer assumes both load and source are matched to the same reference impedance of the network.